# Difference between @PathVariable and @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm confused with @PathVariable and @ModelAttribute in SpringFramework. Can I know what are the differences between?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) @PathVariable**

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a URI template variable

ex: You have one URL like this `http:/myweb/transferfund/john/john123`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/transferfund/{user}/john123")
public String index(@PathVariable String user){
System.out.println("Logged User :"+user);
}
```

Base on above example,you can get the variable from URI using `@PathVariable` which in this case will print out `john`.
You also can fetch another part of URI like this;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/transferfund/john/{userID}")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{transaction}/john/john123")
```

You even can do like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{transaction}")
```

which will catch any URl that doesnt have their own `@RequestMapping`

**2) @ModelAttribute**

> Annotation that binds a method parameter or method return value to a named model attribute, exposed to a web view

ex: You have one form:

```
<form:form action="/addUser" modelAttribute="userInfo">
<form:input path="name" value="John Doe">
<form:input path="id" value="john123">
</form:form>
```

And in your `@RequestMapping`

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser")
        public String index(@ModelAttribute("userInfo") User userinfo){
        System.out.println("Registered User :"+userinfo.getUserName());
        }
```

Based on the example,the system will print out `Registered User : John Doe`
But you need this spring taglib to use `@ModelAttribute` :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

**@PathVariable**

1. @PathVariable is very useful for dynamic URIs.
2. There is no limit on the number of parameters used in a single
   method.
3. You can use more than one dynamic parameter in a single
   method’s parameter.
4. @PathVariable argument can be of any simple
   type such as int, long, Date, etc.

**@ModelAttribute**

1. The name of the model attribute to bind to.